# CSS Style Nesting - Proper Form?

Tags: css, nested

I am having a problem trying to find any specific details on how to properly write CSS rules in a stylesheet where the class or ID is nested within many other IDs and styles, e.g.

```css
.mainbody #container #header #toprightsearch .searchbox {}
```

So here we have a `searchbox` class within a `toprightsearch` ID, in a header ID, in a container ID, in a `mainbody` class.

But it appears to work properly if I omit some of the IDs.

What is the *correct* way of listing these?
If I include all of the parents does it make it more specific?
Can it error on different browsers if I don't include all?

And any additional information on this topic would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you include more parents, it does increase selector specificity.  You shouldn't have cross-browser problems omitting parents.

There is no *correct* number of parents to list; it depends on what you require for your markup.  As you're seeing, `selector1 selector2` means a `selector2` at any level inside a `selector1`, and you can tune that for whatever behavior you need.

In your example, you should list `.mainbody #container #header #toprightsearch .searchbox` if what you *mean* is for the style to only apply to `.searchbox`es that are inside that entire hierarchy.  If contrariwise you want `.searchboxes` that exist other under conditions to get the same style, you should be less restrictive in the hierarchy.  It's only about what you're trying to accomplish.

Re comment: IDs produce more specificity, so omitting them reduces your rule's specificity more.

Comment: Ok - and is there any difference in omitting IDs vs Classes?

Answer (score 35):

```
.searchbox {}
```

Styles anything with .searchbox

```
.mainbody .searchbox{}
```

Styles any .searchbox that descends from any .mainbody, direct child, grandchild, quadruple great grandchild, doesn't matter.

```
#toprightsearch > .searchbox {}
```

Styles only .searchboxes that are direct children of #toprightsearch

```
#container * .searchbox {}
```

Styles .searchbox's that are grandchild or later of #container.

Here's a good document on the topic: [w3C selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

Answer (score 4):

Id's are specific to the page.  So you'd just use

```
#toprightsearch {
 stylename: stylevalue;
}
```

If your looking for nested classes then the correct format is

```
.header .textBoxes {
  stylename: stylevalue;
}
```

If you know the exact child of a parent then you use the > sign. So if your document was like this:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="menu">
         <input type="text" class="textBox" />
    </div>
</div>
```

You can use this:

```
 .header > .menu > .textBox {somestyle:somevalue;}
```

This means only items with a .textBox class directly inside of a .menu class item which is itself directly below an element with a class of .header.

Answer (score 2):

From the [W3 Selectors Documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors):

> Descendant selectors express such a relationship in a pattern. A descendant selector is made up of two or more selectors separated by white space. A descendant selector of the form "A B" matches when an element B is an arbitrary descendant of some ancestor element A.

So in short, no you do not have to include *all* of the parent elements, and should not cause any cross-browser problems. However, with this selector:

```
.mainbody .searchbox {}
```

The styles defined will apply to any element with a class of `searchbox` whether it descends directly or indirectly from an element with class `mainbody`.

With your proposed selector, however:

```
.mainbody #container #header #toprightsearch .searchbox {}
```

The styles defined are more specific, and so only elements that descend from an element with class `mainbody`, then the elements with IDs of `#container`, `#header`, `#toprightsearch` in that order and that have a class name `searchbox` will have the defined styles applied.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, an ID should only be used for one specific item on a page. So you should only have one item with an ID of `toprightsearch` so, for your CSS to work you only need to indicate:

```
#toprightsearch .searchbox {}
```

because there is only one item on your page with an ID of `toprightsearch`, All the other selectors are unnecessary.

If you have two items on your page with an ID of `toprightsearch` then that is bad coding practice.

Answer (score 0):

The code below does what it says (at least in Firefox). it colors the input red

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.mainbody #container #header #toprightsearch .searchbox {
    background-color:red;
}
</style>
</head>

<body class="mainbody">

<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="toprightsearch">
            <input type="text" class="searchbox" />
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I think you should see if there went anything wrong in spelling the ID's and classes.

Comment: thanks, but I'm not having a problem making it work. I just noticed that it works sometimes if I omit parent ids and classes. So I am looking for the correct way to list rules.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this has issues. This was a very good answer to the question it sounded like razass was asking.

Comment: The question was why you could omit some of the combinators and still get the same result--not a "this is busted" question but a "why does this still work?" question.  It was probably down voted because it appears that jao didn't read the question carefully (I didn't down vote this however)